# Abstract class return in interface

Tags: java, abstract-class

First of all, pretty new in java, sorry if it is a simple question.

I have implemented an abstract class, and two classes that extends it.

```
public abstract class Lado{
//body
}
```

and the two other classes with this form for example

```
public class Arista extends Lado
{ //body
}
```

so, no problem there, now i have an interface defined like this.

```
public interface Grafo
{  //body
   public List<Lado> lados();
   //more body
}
```

has you see the interface returns a List of class Lado,
but in my implementation I need to return a List of class Arista or the second class (on another implementation of the interface)

in the codebase that I HAVE to use for the interface implementation have the implementation of lados() like this

```
    public List<Lado> lados() {
        return lados;
    }
```

with lados defined in my code like

```
   private List<Arista> lados;
```

and initialized

```
  lados = new LinkedList<Arista>();
```

now of course the return gives an error

```
GrafoNoDirigido.java:141: error: incompatible types
    return lados;
           ^
   required: List<Lado>
   found:    List<Arista>
1 error
```

I cant seem to find how to fix this without modifying the base code that was given to me (and I repeat cant change it). I know I cant instantiate an abstract class object and the abstract class implementation has values and functions that the abstract class doesn't.

Also I cant use override for the same reason that i cant change my functions signatures in my implementations.

I'll appreciate your help, thanks.

If anything reads weird, please let me know.

-------------------- EDIT ---------
Lado abstract class.

```
public abstract class Lado
{
   private String id;
   private double peso;

   public Lado(String id, double peso) {
      this.id = id;
      this.peso = peso;
   }

   public String getId() {
      return id;
   }

   public double getPeso() {
        return peso;
   }

   public abstract String toString();

 }
```

Arista subclass

```
public class Arista extends Lado
{
   private Vertice u;
   private Vertice v;

   public Arista(String id, double peso, Vertice u, Vertice v){
      super(id , peso);
      this.u = u;
      this.v = v;
   }

   public Vertice getExtremo1() {
     return u;
   }

   public Vertice getExtremo2() {
     return v;
   }


   public String toString() {
     String s = "string";
     return s;
   }

}
```

Then if I return a  `List<Lado>` if y try to do `getExtremo1()` it doenst find the symbol on compilation (no existant on the Lado class), tried to cast the output list like a `List<Arista>` but it didnt worked correctly either.

Comment: The solution is to change the return type in the interface `Grafo` to be `List<? extends Lado>`. However, if you aren't allowed to change that, you're stuck.

Comment: Q: Which of your classes actually *implements* Grafo?

Comment: @FoggyDay the class is implemented in a class called GrafoDirigido and another one called Digrafo, this two work at 90% I just need to make the lados() function to work correctly.

pbabcdefp yes it works, unfortunately  I cant change the function base signature that was given to me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your interface to:

<s>public  List lados();</s>

```
public List<? extends Lado> lados();
```

-- OR --

You can go another route and have the list be of the parent type with child instances:

```
private List<Lado> lados;

@Override
public List<Lado> lados() {
    // Type of lados is List<Lado>, but we will fill it up with Arista instances...
    lados = new LinkedList<Lados>();
    lados.add(new Arista());
    // if Arista has methods that follow the with setter stereotype, ie: public Arista withId(int id) { this.setId(id); return this; } you can in-line create them:
    lados.add(new Arista()
              .withId(id)
              .withName(name)
    );
    Arista arista = new Arista();
    lados.add(arista);
    ...
    return lados;
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: @LouisWasserman: I edited and added another --OR-- which will let him not need a generic type.

Comment: @LouisWasserman: Thanks for the heads up, I went ahead and mucked around with some test cases until I found a working alternate to replace there. I fixed it up again, now both should be viable solutions.

Comment: First one works perfectly, unfortunately already got a negative to modifiy the signatures (I don't understand this limitations).

The seconds works but as I have lados() defined as a variable for my class, when I do lados = new LinkedList<Lados>(); it works on the return, but if I do anything else like iterate on the list and then use a method on one of the objects then I have erros cause the compiler sees them like Lado and not like Arista. Thanks, this was the one question that worked the best

Comment: @AlejandroDiaz: I'd need to see your iteration code to see specifically what the issue there is, but you could do something like: `for (Lado lado : implClassInstance.lados()) { if (lado instanceof Arista) { Arista arista = (Arista)lado; // do more stuff here on arista. } }`, but there may be a better way to scale the code if there's more known about the behaviour model and implementation.

Comment: Something in the lines of with getId() function from Arista and not on Lados, dont want to put full code cause is pretty extensive. If I use Arista elements to get an Arista it fails, if use lado ant try getId() it fails too. hope it helps to understand better the error.

`ListIterator<Lado> iterator = lados.listIterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()){
            Lado element = iterator.next();
            if(element.getId().equals("string"))
                return element;
        }`

Comment: @AlejandroDiaz: Does `Lado` have a `getId()` method. If it does and `Arista` overrides it, you should end up with the result from the child. See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29997018/super-issue-error-expected/29997410#29997410 or also my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29710567/inheriting-methods-from-other-classes/29710785#29710785. Without seeing the relevant parts of each class, it's hard to help with the design or know that we offered the best solution.

Comment: @anonymous in this case Lado does not have a getId(), and thats why it fails when I try to call it in the list that I return with the seconds answer. Let me try to update my question.

Answer (score 1):

Since class Artista is also Lado class, your initialization should be

```
List<Lado> lados = new LinkedList<>();
:
lados.add(new Artista (..));
:
return lados;
```

Comment: It works, but creates other problems, for example is i iterate on the list then the compiler is going to see each element as it is of class lado, and if I need to use some methos of the Arista class it fails.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: When iterating ask the object what class it is by using instanceOf operator.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Java doesn't have good support for "variance" for Enumerations (and no, it's not a simple question). Look here, under "The Workaround" for a solution: https://schneide.wordpress.com/tag/upcast/

Answer (score 0):

If you can't change either the method return type or the variable declaration, you can return a copy:

```
public List<Lado> lados() {
    return new LinkedList<Lado>(lados);
}
```

Or you can return a wrapper:

```
public List<Lado> lados() {
    return java.util.Collections.unmodifiableList(lados);
}
```

Comment: Copying works, just need to check if when i catch that return i can see check properties or functions of the Arista class.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score -1):

So these are your constraints:

- you can't change the lados() method return type (`List<Lado>`).
- you want your field to be of the `List<Arista>`

**1. Copying the array**

```
public List<Lado> lados() {
    return new ArrayList<>(lados);
}
```

**2. Wrapping it as unmodifiable list***

```
public List<Lado> lados() {
    return Collections.unmodifiableList(lados);
}
```

**3. Type erasure, don't do it, this is unsafe**

Erasing the generics of your field before returning it. Unsafe since if someone adds an object that extends `Lado` but it's not `Arista` to that list you will have [HeapPolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_pollution).

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<Lado> lados() {
    return (List)lados;
}
```

Comment: This is a terrible idea which compromises type safety and can lead to heap pollution.

Comment: Whether it compiles is not the issue. `class Foo extends Lado {} new GraphoImpl().lados().add(new Foo());` It's **not** safe and **nobody** should use it.

Comment: ok you're worried about someone modifying that list. point noted. I've modified the answer to reflect your contribution.

Comment: You should just delete the raw type idea. It's bad enough without people actually recommending it. It just leads to ridiculous bugs [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29666610/classcastexception-cant-be-cast-to-java-lang-integer) and people like me have to come by and figure it out.

Comment: Nah. It's dangerous knowledge but it's knowledge.