# Can a method return an abstract class type?

Tags: java, return-type

I am looking the method `getCurrencyInstance()` in `NumberFormat` class and I see that this method has a return type of `NumberFormat`.

What does it mean?

I am a little confused because I know that we can create an object of an abstract class. So this method returns an object and if this method doesn't return an object what does it return?

Comment: if return type is NumberFormat, then it actually returns a NumberFormat

Comment: There has to be a duplicate to this question as I do recall it being asked not infrequently... but can't find it.

Comment: I don't understand -- "NumberFormat" is easy to look up on line.  What explanations did you find, and what don't you understand about them?

Comment: @Prune: he's unclear on the basic underpinnings of a variable declaration vs an instance, a key concept that all newbie programmers must learn well (and he will get it soon, I'm sure). A return type is just a declaration, but the concrete class that it returns is the instance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Abstract class return in interface](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30008922/abstract-class-return-in-interface)

Answer (score 6):

In Java, a method can return an abstract class or interface type. What will actually be returned is an object that implements that interface, or extends that abstract class.

The static method NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance() will return a concrete object that extends NumberFormat. In the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html) you can see there are two direct known subclasses: ChoiceFormat and DecimalFormat. There may be more implementations and what is actually returned depends on the implementation of the JVM that you are using.